# Listening to recently added documents that matches a given query

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to listen to a subset of documents added to an Elasticsearch index. The subset is defined by an Elasticsearch query. I can tolerate a 10 second delay between the index operation and the listening callback.

Obviously, I can do this by sending search requests to the server every 10 seconds. But searching the entire index for recent documents seems redundant. I can store the id of the last document I've fetched and use that to narrow down the search further, which I will do if there is no easier way.

I thought, however, there may be a plugin that will catch any newly inserted document, try to match the query against the document and push it to my listener if the match was successful. Does such plugin exists? Is this at least possible?

Comment: Percolator seems to have been discontinued, I get 404 for link in  @knutwalker 's answer, do you know of any current alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Percolator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-percolate.html) feature, which does what you described. Also, there are significant changes in the upcoming 1.0 release, see: [Master Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/_percolator.html)

**Edit**: As of Elasticsearch 5.0, the Percolator [has been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-percolate.html) and replaced with the [percolator query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/query-dsl-percolate-query.html)

Comment: Wow! How did I miss that? Thank you. I'll check it out.

Comment: Percolator seems to have been discontinued, I get 404 for link you shared, do you know of any current alternative?

Comment: @Tingya percolator has been removed in favor of the percolator query, i've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @EserAygün Can you explain how you managed to use percolator to listen for only the newly added documents?  It sounds like percolator is more to do with querying rather than listening for the recently added documents.

Answer (score 0):

the delay depends on how many queries you need to match. recently, I've test the percolate feature in the 1.0 beta version. to percolate one document via 100 registered queries, less than 10ms, 1000, above 15ms, 10000 above 100ms, seems the delay increase linearly with the number of 
registered queries. very bad. after reading "how does it work under the hook" section of beta 1.0 percolate documentation, I'm confirmed that the "percolating" is done in a linear way.